# Exception when querying a table with field BIT : JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am working with JPQL. i have a table in which fields are

```
1. Name DataType-varchar

2. sub DataType-BIT
```

in **POJO** file

```
private String name;

private byte sub;
```

insertion is successfull as:

Name= John
sub=0

Now when i query for this table using :

```
   query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Sample c WHERE c.name = '"+ (name)+ "'", Sample.class);
```

**Exception** occurs:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [false], of class [class java.lang.Boolean], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[sub-->sample.SUB]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(com.org.Test --> [DatabaseTable(sample)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Byte].
```

I think when getting the values its internally taking bit as false.
how can i resolve this problem??

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Boolean here.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set the type to boolean instead of byte in your model classes.